# Twilio SMS not being sent with my purchased phone number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm using the code from the documentation to send a SMS to a mexican number and it works.

But the sms is being sent from another phone number other than the one I purchased. I want to be able to send back a reply and visualize it on the Twilio Console. I have tried sending a sms directly to my number and I can see it there, but if I send a reply to the phone number that sent me the sms a get nothing. How can I send an SMS from the number I purchased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It is likely that you are sending SMS messages to a country that doesn't support maintaining the sender ID. Check out the [SMS guidelines](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/us) for the country you are sending to to see if this should be supported or not.